# Related data not being added for existing parent entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Im trying to save a rating against a place, I have the code below, but it doesnt seems to save rating (to the ratings table) for an existing entity

```
 place.Ratings.Add(rating);
  _placeRepository.AddPlaceIfItDoesntExist(place);
  _placeRepository.Save();
```

This is the repository method

```
 public void AddPlaceIfItDoesntExist(Place place)
        {
            var placeItem = context.Places.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GooglePlaceId == place.GooglePlaceId);
            if(placeItem==null)
            {
                context.Places.Add(place);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Entry(placeItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
```

and this is the poco

```
 public class Place
 {
        public Place()
        {
            Ratings = new List<Rating>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string GooglePlaceId { get; set; }
 }
```

I think the crux of the problem is because i need to check if the place exists based on googleplaceid(a string) rather than the id (both are unique per place btw)

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
context.Entry(placeItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

you just mark the existing `placeItem` object as modified. But it's a different instance than the passed `place` object, hence contains the **orginal** values.

Instead, replace that line with:

```
context.Entry(placeItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(place);
```

Alternatively, you can use the [DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbsetmigrationsextensions.addorupdate(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate<code>1%28System.Data.Entity.IDbSet%7B</code>0%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B<code>0,System.Object%7D%7D,</code>0[]%29) method overload that allows you to pass a custom identification expression:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

public void AddPlaceIfItDoesntExist(Place place)
{
    context.Places.AddOrUpdate(p => p.GooglePlaceId, place);
}
```

Comment: the first method gives an error The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Comment: Could be specific to your usage. Try `place.Id = placeItem.Id;` before calling `SetValues`.